# How do you bind the ListView.SelectedItem property to a ViewModel in MVVM?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

I am currently working on a UWP MVVM project that requires the end user to select an item from a list, then click a button. The buttons, and the commands they are linked to, use the SelectedItem property to detect which object the end user wants to edit or delete. I am using the MVVM pattern with Fody (so INotificationPropertyChanged is already implemented). The issue is that none of the buttons, nor their functions, are working because the property always returns "null".

Here is the XAML View:

```
<ListView ItemsSource = "{x:Bind ViewModel.EmployeeListing, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedEmployee, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ObjectToEmployeeConverter}}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Employee">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width = "auto" />
                </ Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                < TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" Text="{x:Bind DisplayName, Mode=OneWay}">
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.Footer>
        <StackPanel Orientation = "Horizontal" >
            < Button Margin="8" x:Uid="Employees_Edit" Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.EditEmployeeCommand}" IsEnabled="{x:Bind ViewModel.IsEmployeeSelected}"/>
            <Button Margin = "8" x:Uid="Employees_Remove" Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.RemoveEmployeeCommand}" IsEnabled="{x:Bind ViewModel.IsEmployeeSelected}"/>
            <Button Margin = "8" x:Uid="Employees_Add" Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.NewEmployeeCommand}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListView.Footer>
</ListView>
```

My ViewModel:

```
[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public class EmployeesViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> EmployeeListing { get; set; }

    public Employee SelectedEmployee { get; set; } //NOT currently responding to change in selected item

    public bool IsNewEmployee; //True if creating a chart of account. False is editing one.
    public Employee NewEmployeeBuffer; //Used when creating a new accont (Discarded if Cancel, Added if Save)

    public bool IsEmployeeSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return SelectedEmployee != null;
        }
    }
    public ICommand EditEmployeeCommand;
    public ICommand RemoveEmployeeCommand;
    public ICommand NewEmployeeCommand;
    public ICommand SaveEditedEmployeeCommand;
    public ICommand CancelCommand;

    public EmployeesViewModel()
    {
        Task.Run(SetEmployeeListing).Wait();
    }
    private async Task SetEmployeeListing()
    {
        EmployeeListing = await Employee.EmployeeListing();
    }
}
```

And finally, my Converter:

```
public class ObjectToEmployeeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value as Employee; //No data
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value as object; //Data loss
    }
}
```

I very much appreciate any help on this. I've been stuck for awhile

Comment: Why are you using an `IValueConverter` on that binding?

Comment: Could you use a oneway binding and subscribe to the SelectionChanged event instead? Also, without putting more effort into this, I can't tell what type value is in ObjectToEmployeeConverter.  If it is not of a type compatible cast as Employee, that would cause the returned value to be null.

Comment: @ClayVerValen That would violate MVVM

Comment: @BradleyUffner For whatever reason, a two-way x:Bind would not compile because it has to convert an object into an Employee or vise versa. I know inheritance should make it work, but it isn't.

Comment: Too much to read now, I suspect the converter is involved in this somehow. Simplify your tasks.  Here's how to do it correctly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280586/c-sharp-net4-wpf-set-combobox-selecteditem-from-a-string/3280796#3280796 compare that to what you're doing and stop doing whatever isn't at that link.

Comment: You don't need the additional casting inside your converter, you just need `return value;` for x:Bind to work.